# What is an alternative, succinct phrase for something that is not prone to errors?

Tags: terminology

What is an alternative, succinct phrase for something that is not prone to errors, i.e. the antonym of error-prone? "Error-free" is too extreme in that it suggests infallibility.

Comment: What's the context? It may help to find the right connotation.

Comment: @Bradd: I second the call for more context. I might talk about _robust_ software, a _dependable_ truck, a _trustworthy_ counselor, and a _secure_ connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want:

> **Reliable** 2: giving the same result on successive trials

*from m-w.com*

> **Reliability**: The probability that a product will perform its specified function under prescribed conditions without failure for a specified period of time.

*from APICS.org dictionary (on-line, 13th ed.)*

Comment: +1 However, technical definitions of *reliability*, *robustness* and related terms are more relevant to the context than general English dictionary meanings.

Comment: Agreed and edited as such for "reliability;" cannot find justification to match "robustness" with the OP based on my source.  Please update if you can improve on this.

Comment: http://www.linfo.org/robust.html

Answer (score 2):

*Reliable, steady, stable,* or *high-quality* may work, depending on the context. If that's not quite right, try those words as a starting point in a thesaurus.

Comment: Downvoter: Can you please offer feedback that would help improve the answer? I'm frankly puzzled that this got a downvote when it includes the same word as the upvoted and accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about "safer"? I know it's not specific to the pass/fail rate of a working unit, but it does imply that it's fairly good but definitely not perfect.

Answer (score -1):

I like peerless for describing a human trait.